# Using sqlite3 ,How to only get the primary keys from a table with SELECT

Tags: select, sqlite

I am using sqlite3

The reason I want to use SELECT is because I want to add WHERE clauses eventually as well. I only want it to return the primary key. This is because this is apart of the C callback function in sqlite3 to get primary keys based on a WHERE provided.

My attempts have been.. all obviously do not work. The 'PRIMARY KEY' version actually finds all the records but then just lists PRIMARY KEY.. which I found amusing. Id will only work if the key is actually called Id, which it might not always be.

```
 SELECT tablename.pk from tablename;
 SELECT 'PRIMARY KEY' from tablename;  
 SELECT Id from from tablename
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Currently my solution has been to just add a parameter in the C function for the name of the primary key and place that in after SELECT. It is not ideal, as it does require the key to actually be known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://marc.info/?l=sqlite-users&m=107265641804362&w=2 ... The 6th column of the result of the TABLE_INFO pragma is true
for primary key columns and false for other columns.